# Flot: Format Tick Labels

Tags: flot

How can I format the axis/tick labels labels ?

What if I need to change the font-style and font-size ?

I referred to the following question but was unsuccessful:

[Tickformatter not performing as expected in latest version of Flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930838/tickformatter-not-performing-as-expected-in-latest-version-of-flot)

Please Help !!!

Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following:

**CSS File/SCSS File**

```
#graph_label .tickLabel{

    font-size: 50%;
 }
```

**Index.html or place where you are plotting the graph area**

```
$.plot($("graph_label"), [dataArrayReference], options);
```

**PS: I am using Flot Version prior to 0.8.1 so I dont have any idea about how latest version would work**

Answer (score 5):

If you're using 0.8, just override `.flot-tick-label` in your stylesheet.  You can get more specific via the flot-[x|y]-axis classes.

See the [customizing the axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) section of the docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I've fixed issue this way:

```
var _chart = $.plot($(element).find('[flot-placeholder]'), dataset, chartOptions);

$(element).find('.tickLabel').css('color', 'blue'); // fix
```